# Backbone.js Model validation fails to prevent Model from saving

Tags: backbone.js

I have defined a validate method for a Backbone.js Model.  The problem is that even if validation fails (i.e. the Model.validate method returns a value) the post/put request is still sent to the server.  This contradicts what is explained in the Backbone.js documentation.  I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

The following is the Model definition:

```js
/**
 * Model - Contact
 */
var Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: '/contacts.json',
  idAttribute: '_id',
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      surname: '',
      given_name: '',
      org: '',
      phone: new Array(),
      email: new Array(),
      address: new Array({
        street: '',
        district: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        postcode: ''
      })
    };
  }
  validate: function(attributes) {
    if (typeof attributes.validationDisabled === 'undefined') {
      var errors = new Array();
      // Validate surname.
      if (_.isEmpty(attributes.surname) === true) {
        errors.push({
          type: 'form',
          attribute: 'surname',
          message: 'Please enter a surname.'
        });
      }
      // Validate emails.
      if (_.isEmpty(attributes.email) === false) {
        var emailRegex = /^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i;
        // Stores indexes of email values which fail validation.
        var emailIndex = new Array();
        _.each(attributes.email, function(email, index) {
          if (emailRegex.test(email.value) === false) {
            emailIndex.push(index);
          }
        });
        // Create error message.
        if (emailIndex.length > 0) {
          errors.push({
            type: 'form',
            attribute: 'email',
            index: emailIndex,
            message: 'Please enter valid email address.'
          });
        }
      }

      if (errors.length > 0) {
        console.log('Form validation failed.');
        return errors;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Here is the View which calls the Model.save() method (see: method saveContact() below). Note that other methods belonging to this View have not been included below for reasons of brevity.

```js
/** 
 * View - Edit contact form 
 */
var EditContactFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'createDialog', 'formError', 'render', 'saveContact', 'updateContact');
    // Add templates.
    this._editFormTemplate = _.template($('#edit-contact-form-tpl').html());
    this._emailFieldTemplate = _.template($('#email-field-tpl').html());
    this._phoneFieldTemplate = _.template($('#phone-field-tpl').html());
    // Get URI of current page.
    this.currentPageUri = this.options.currentPageUri;
    // Create array to hold references to all subviews. 
    this.subViews = new Array();
    // Set options for new or existing contact.
    this.model = this.options.model;
    // Bind with Model validation error event.
    this.model.on('error', this.formError);
    this.render();
  }
  /**
   * Deals with form validation errors
   */
  formError: function(model, error) {
    console.log(error);
  },
  saveContact: function(event) {
    var self = this;
    // Prevent submit event trigger from firing.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Trigger form submit event.
    eventAggregator.trigger('submit:contactEditForm');
    // Update model with form values.
    this.updateContact();
    // Enable validation for Model.  Done by unsetting validationDisabled
    // attribute. This setting was formerly applied to prevent validation 
    // on Model.fetch() events. See this.model.validate(). 
    this.model.unset('validationDisabled');
    // Save contact to database.
    this.model.save(this.model.attributes, {
      success: function(model, response) {
        if (typeof response.flash !== 'undefined') {
          Messenger.trigger('new:messages', response.flash);
        }
      },
      error: function(model, response) {
        console.log(response);
        throw error = new Error('Error occured while trying to save contact.');
      },
      wait: true 
    });
  },
  /**
   * Extract form values and update Contact.
   */
  updateContact: function() {
    this.model.set('surname', this.$('#surname-field').val());
    this.model.set('given_name', this.$('#given-name-field').val());
    this.model.set('org', this.$('#org-field').val());
    // Extract address form values.
    var address = new Array({
      street: this.$('input[name="street"]').val(),
      district: this.$('input[name="district"]').val(),
      city: this.$('input[name="city"]').val(),
      country: this.$('input[name="country"]').val(),
      postcode: this.$('input[name="postcode"]').val()
    });
    this.model.set('address', address);
  }
});
```

Comment: just for sake of simplicity. Did you try returning just a string from the validate method? Have you debugged your code and checked to see if the Errors array is indeed returned? awaiting your response ":)

Comment: @Deeptechtons: the errors array is being returned to function formError() in the View.  But the error callback for Model.save() is not being called (it always calls the success callback instead).

Comment: @Benjen instead try this `this.model.save({}, {
      success: function(model, response) {
        if (typeof response.flash !== 'undefined') {
          Messenger.trigger('new:messages', response.flash);
        }
      },
      error: function(model, response) {
        console.log(response);
        throw error = new Error('Error occured while trying to save contact.');
      }`

Comment: @Deeptechtons I tried making the changes but it but is still doesn't work.

Comment: @Benjen May be you could try replicating the problem with a JSFiddle ? then we can make sure where the problem is arising from

Comment: @Deeptechtons: I have made a mock up on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bengul/eWcD7/3/). I wasn't sure how to replicate DB storage on Model.save(), so I have implemented [Backbone-localstorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) to mimic it. As you can see, the model is being saved even though the validation is failing on the email attribute.

Comment: @Benjen Could you tell more about what input i should provide in text areas?

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Try this version instead [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bengul/eWcD7/5/). Sorry I should have realized that when one sees text areas and a save button, then one would assume that they need to enter something.  Actually, there is no user input.  trigger the save event by pressing the button. The text areas are to show what is happening.  First one shows which callback is run after running Model.save().  The second textarea shows the response from the model error event. This shows whether Model.validate is working or not, and displays the returned value from Model.validate().